# Execution failed for task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

After adding Admob in Unity, the following error appeared:

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

Please suggest the possible solution for this error.

Comment: Hey Arimantos, it will be much easier for other users to help you if you add some of the following, more debug information or logging data, the code generating the error, and a little more detail in general. Good luck.